# How to export Oracle schema and user detail in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

in sqldeveloper there is a useful tool for exporting on a sql file all the object that exist on a schema.

Anyhow i am unable to find something similar for exporting the schema and user informations.

The sqldeveloper version i'm using is 3.2

Thanks, Piwakkio.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  OBJECTDDL CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (select * from user_objects WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN(/*WHATEVER YOU WANT*/) ) LOOP
    select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(I.OBJECT_TYPE,I.OBJECT_NAME) INTO OBJECTDDL from dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OBJECTDDL);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: So there is no tool for automating this but you have to do this by hand.
I will give your query a try, many thanks.

Comment: The object type stored in the user_objects table are the following 'PROCEDURE, PACKAGE, PACKAGE BODY, TRIGGER, TABLE, VIEW, INDEX, FUNCTION, TYPE' not the user/schema details i was seaching for.